# ¿Por qué git push no hace nada?

Tags: linux, git, git-push

Hace poco actualicé mi Linux Mint a la versión 18.1. Eso implicó reinstalarlo casi todo, incluido el `git`.

Desde entonces, cada vez que creo una nueva rama (`git checkout -b feature-mi_tarea`), la primera vez que hago un `git push` me dice que no hay nada que hacer. Anteriormente en esta primera ocasión me decía que no existía la rama remota y sugería que hiciera algo así como:

```
git branch --set-upstream mi_tarea upstream/mi_tarea
```

Pero ahora simplemente dice que todo está al día:

```
$ git push
Everything up-to-date
```

Si lo fuerzo con `git push origin <rama_remota>` sí funciona:

```
$ git push origin feature-mi_tarea
Counting objects: 13, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
Writing objects: 100% (13/13), 2.18 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 13 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: 
remote: To create a merge request for feature-mi_tarea, visit:
remote:   http://gitlab.miempresa.com/blabla/bleble/merge_requests/new?merge_request%5Bsource_branch%5D=feature-mi_tarea
remote: 
To git@gitlab.miempresa.com:blabla/bleble.git
 * [new branch]      feature-mi_tarea -> feature-mi_tarea
```

Esta es mi configuración:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@gitlab.miempresa.com:blabla/bleble.git (fetch)
origin  git@gitlab.miempresa.com:blabla/bleble.git (push)
```

[Hay quien sugiere hacer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22933955/1983854):

```
git config --global push.default current
```

Lo probé y parece que funciona, pero no sé si es lo adecuado.

Comment: Sí funciona pero ¿Dices que creas un nuevo branch en local y te deja pushear sin primero pedirte `--set-upstream`? eso está raro.

Comment: @amenadiel exactamente. Anteriormente hacía esto de `git push origin feature-mi_tarea`, pero con `git config --global push.default current` me deja hacer `git push` sin más.

Comment: Ah, ya veo. En mi caso uso `git config --global push.default simple` y la primera vez siempre me pide elegir el upstream

Comment: @amenadiel acabo de probar la configuración que mencionas y ¡funciona! Supongo que `push.default current` debía coger la que tuviera (que no sé cuál es), que era muy laxa.

Comment: @amenadiel volví a esta pregunta... dale a responder con el comentario, para que pueda marcarlo como respuesta aceptada. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El comportamiento de

```
$ git push
```

Depende de lo que haya en el setting global `push.default`.

Si lo que quieres es que, después de haber creado una rama nueva, el primer `git push` te pida definir un upstream, entonces debieras configurar el setting como:

```
git config --global push.default simple
```

El comportamiento de `simple` es que tus ramas locales pushean a la rama que están trackeando. Si no están vinculados a una rama remota entonces te va a reclamar. **No importa si hay una rama remota con el mismo nombre**, hasta que no uses `--set-upstream` se negará a pushear.

La diferencia con usar el setting `current` es que current pushea a una rama del mismo nombre, sin importar si alguna vez declaraste explícitamente que se correspondía con tu rama local.